# Characterizing property of $g$ such that $gag^{-1}=b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Is there some characterizing property for an element $g$ of minimal length such that 
$gag^{-1}=b$?

We know that if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are both such that $g_1ag_1^{-1}=b$ and $g_2ag_2^{-1}=b$ then they belong to the same coset of the stabilizer of $a$ under conjugation.

Are there any known results about the structure of the coset decomposition in this case? I am particularly interested in the case of the symmetric group.

Comment: Well, conjugacy classes in $S_n$ are just cycle types, so I guess finding the minimum length such $g$ corresponds to finding which cycles you want to send to which cycles.  Sounds like it could lead to a potentially hard combinatorial optimization problem.  (But that's just speculation.)

Comment: What do you mean by the coset decomposition?

Comment: The key phrase is "the conjugacy search problem". There has been some serious research on the CSP recently, especially of Braid groups. This is related to cryptography, so is considered "sexy". Braid groups are related to symmetric groups, so you might want to look at some papers on the arXiv and see if you can find anything useful. I do not know anything about the CSP for symmetric groups though.